# I got IndexError: Target 3 is out of bounds. Error on making model from CNN module in line loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

my code is like this and i do everything to found error but it doesnot work
import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.autograd import Variable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

```
#Transformation for image
transform_ori = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(64),   #create 64x64 image
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),    #flipping the image horizontally
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),                 #convert the image to a Tensor
                                    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])  #normalize the image

#Load our dataset
train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = '/content//Data',
                                     transform = transform_ori)

test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = '/content/Data',
                                    transform = transform_ori)

#Make the dataset iterable
batch_size = 100
train_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = True)

batch_size = 100
train_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = True)      #Shuffle to create a mixed batches of 100 of cat & dog images

test_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = False)

#Show a batch of images
def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))

# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(train_load)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))

print("There are {} images in train set".format(len(train_dataset)))
print("There are {} images in train loader".format(len(train_load)))
print("There are {} images in test set".format(len(test_dataset)))
print("There are {} images in test loader".format(len(test_load)))

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()
        
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=1)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)        #Batch normalization
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()                 #RELU Activation
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)   #Maxpooling reduces the size by kernel size. 64/2 = 32
        
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)    #Size now is 32/2 = 16
        
        #Flatten the feature maps. You have 32 feature mapsfrom cnn2. Each of the feature is of size 16x16 --> 32*16*16 = 8192
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=8192, out_features=4000)   #Flattened image is fed into linear NN and reduced to half size
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)                    #Dropout used to reduce overfitting
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=4000, out_features=2000)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=2000, out_features=500)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=500, out_features=50)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=2)    #Since there were so many features, I decided to use 45 layers to get output layers. You can increase the kernels in Maxpooling to reduce image further and reduce number of hidden linear layers.

def forward(self,x):
        out = self.cnn1(x)
        out = self.batchnorm1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.maxpool1(out)
        out = self.cnn2(out)
        out = self.batchnorm2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.maxpool2(out)
        #Flattening is done here with .view() -> (batch_size, 32*16*16) = (100, 8192)
        out = out.view(-1,8192)   #-1 will automatically update the batchsize as 100; 8192 flattens 32,16,16
        #Then we forward through our fully connected layer 
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc4(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc5(out)
        return out

model = CNN()
CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
if CUDA:
    model = model.cuda()    
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()        
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

import time

num_epochs = 50

#Define the lists to store the results of loss and accuracy
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

#Training
for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
    #Reset these below variables to 0 at the begining of every epoch
    start = time.time()
    correct = 0
    iterations = 0
    iter_loss = 0.0
    
    model.train()                   # Put the network into training mode
    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_load):
        
      # Convert torch tensor to Variable
      Inputs = Variable(inputs)
      Labels = Variable(labels)
      
      # If we have GPU, shift the data to GPU
      CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
      if CUDA:
        print("Cuda is Available!")
        Inputs = Inputs.cuda()
        Labels = Labels.cuda()

      optimizer.zero_grad()
      outputs = model(inputs)       
      
      loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)  
      iter_loss += loss.data[0]       # Accumulate the loss
      loss.backward()                 # Backpropagation 
      optimizer.step()                # Update the weights
      
      # Record the correct predictions for training data 
      _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
      correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
      iterations += 1
    
    # Record the training loss
    train_loss.append(iter_loss/iterations)
    # Record the training accuracy
    train_accuracy.append((100 * correct / len(train_dataset)))
   
    #Testing
    loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    iterations = 0

    model.eval()                    # Put the network into evaluation mode
    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(test_load):
        
        # Convert torch tensor to Variable
        inputs = Variable(inputs)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        
        CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
        if CUDA:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
        
        outputs = model(inputs)     
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels) # Calculate the loss
        loss += loss.data[0]
        # Record the correct predictions for training data
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
        
        iterations += 1

    # Record the Testing loss
    test_loss.append(loss/iterations)
    # Record the Testing accuracy
    test_accuracy.append((100 * correct / len(test_dataset)))
    stop = time.time()
    
    print ('Epoch {}/{}, Training Loss: {:.3f}, Training Accuracy: {:.3f}, Testing Loss: {:.3f}, Testing Acc: {:.3f}, Time: {}s'
           .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, train_loss[-1], train_accuracy[-1], test_loss[-1], test_accuracy[-1], stop-start))
    

# Loss
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(train_loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(test_loss, label='Testing Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Accuracy
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='Testing Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Run this if you want to save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'Cats-Dogs.pth')

#Run this if you want to load the model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Cats-Dogs.pth'))

def predict(img_name,model):
    image = cv2.imread(img_name)   #Read the image
    img = Image.fromarray(image)      #Convert the image to an array
    img = transforms_photo(img)     #Apply the transformations 
    img = img.view(1,3,64,64)       #Add batch size 
    img = Variable(img)      
    #Wrap the tensor to a variable
    
    model.eval()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()
        img = img.cuda()

    output = model(img)
    print(output)
    print(output.data)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output,1)
    if predicted.item()==0:
        p = 'Cat'
    else:
        p = 'Dog'
    cv2.imshow('Original',image)
    return  p
    

pred = predict('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', model)
print("The Predicted Label is {}".format(pred))

#Load the DenseNet
model_conv = torchvision.models.densenet201(pretrained=True)

#Freeze all layers in the network  
for param in model_conv.parameters():  
    param.requires_grad = False
    
#Get the number of inputs of the last layer (or number of neurons in the layer preceeding the last layer)
num_ftrs = model_conv.classifier.in_features

#Reconstruct the last layer (output layer) to have only two classes 
model_conv.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

#Initiate the model on GPU
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model_conv = model_conv.cuda()

#Loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model_conv.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9) #Try Adam optimizer for better accuracy: optim.Adam(model_conv.parameters(), lr=0.001)

#Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

#Training
import time
num_epochs = 20
for epoch in range (num_epochs):
    start = time.time()
    exp_lr_scheduler.step()
    #Reset the correct to 0 after passing through all the dataset
    correct = 0
    for images,labels in dataloaders['training_set']:
        images = Variable(images)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model_conv(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()  
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1) 
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
        
    train_acc = 100 * correct / dataset_sizes['training_set'] 
    stop = time.time()
    print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Train Accuracy: {}%, Time: {:.2f}s'
            .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item(), train_acc, stop-start))
            
    
   #Testing
   model_conv.eval()  
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    start = time.time()
    for (images, labels) in dataloaders['test_set']:
        
        images = Variable(images)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()

        outputs = model_conv(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    stop = time.time()

    print('Test Accuracy: {:.3f} %, Time: {:.2f}s'.format(100 * correct / total,stop-start))

#Import your trial images and check against the model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#Predict your own image
def predict(img_name,model):
    image = cv2.imread(img_name)   #Read the image
    #ret, thresholded = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   #Threshold the image
    img = Image.fromarray(image)      #Convert the image to an array
    img = transforms_photo(img)     #Apply the transformations 
    img = img.view(1,3,224,224)       #Add batch size 
    img = Variable(img)      
   #Wrap the tensor to a variable
    
    model.eval()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()
        img = img.cuda()

    output = model(img)
    print(output)
    print(output.data)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output,1)
    if predicted.item()==0:
        p = 'Cat'
    else:
        p = 'Dog'
    cv2.imshow('Original',image)
    return  p

This question already has answers here:
PyTorch NotImplementedError in forward (2 answers)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 3 days ago.

(Private feedback for you)

here is my code :

import cv2
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.autograd import Variable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

#Transformation for image
transform_ori = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(64),   #create 64x64 image
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),    #flipping the image horizontally
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),                 #convert the image to a Tensor
                                    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])  #normalize the image

#Load our dataset
train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = '/content//Data',
                                     transform = transform_ori)

test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root = '/content/Data',
                                    transform = transform_ori)

#Make the dataset iterable
batch_size = 100
train_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = True)

batch_size = 100
train_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = True)      #Shuffle to create a mixed batches of 100 of cat & dog images

test_load = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = test_dataset, 
                                         batch_size = batch_size,
                                         shuffle = False)

#Show a batch of images
def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))

# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(train_load)
images, labels = dataiter.next()

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))

print("There are {} images in train set".format(len(train_dataset)))
print("There are {} images in train loader".format(len(train_load)))
print("There are {} images in test set".format(len(test_dataset)))
print("There are {} images in test loader".format(len(test_load)))

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()
        
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=1)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)        #Batch normalization
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()                 #RELU Activation
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)   #Maxpooling reduces the size by kernel size. 64/2 = 32
        
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)    #Size now is 32/2 = 16
        
        #Flatten the feature maps. You have 32 feature mapsfrom cnn2. Each of the feature is of size 16x16 --> 32*16*16 = 8192
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=8192, out_features=4000)   #Flattened image is fed into linear NN and reduced to half size
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)                    #Dropout used to reduce overfitting
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=4000, out_features=2000)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=2000, out_features=500)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=500, out_features=50)
        self.droput = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=2)    #Since there were so many features, I decided to use 45 layers to get output layers. You can increase the kernels in Maxpooling to reduce image further and reduce number of hidden linear layers.

def forward(self,x):
        out = self.cnn1(x)
        out = self.batchnorm1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.maxpool1(out)
        out = self.cnn2(out)
        out = self.batchnorm2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.maxpool2(out)
        #Flattening is done here with .view() -> (batch_size, 32*16*16) = (100, 8192)
        out = out.view(-1,8192)   #-1 will automatically update the batchsize as 100; 8192 flattens 32,16,16
        #Then we forward through our fully connected layer 
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc4(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.droput(out)
        out = self.fc5(out)
        return out

model = CNN()
CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
if CUDA:
    model = model.cuda()    
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()        
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

import time

num_epochs = 50

#Define the lists to store the results of loss and accuracy
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

#Training
for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
    #Reset these below variables to 0 at the begining of every epoch
    start = time.time()
    correct = 0
    iterations = 0
    iter_loss = 0.0
    
    model.train()                   # Put the network into training mode
    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_load):
        
      # Convert torch tensor to Variable
      Inputs = Variable(inputs)
      Labels = Variable(labels)
      
      # If we have GPU, shift the data to GPU
      CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
      if CUDA:
        print("Cuda is Available!")
        Inputs = Inputs.cuda()
        Labels = Labels.cuda()

      optimizer.zero_grad()
      outputs = model(inputs)       
      
      loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)  
      iter_loss += loss.data[0]       # Accumulate the loss
      loss.backward()                 # Backpropagation 
      optimizer.step()                # Update the weights
      
      # Record the correct predictions for training data 
      _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
      correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
      iterations += 1
    
    # Record the training loss
    train_loss.append(iter_loss/iterations)
    # Record the training accuracy
    train_accuracy.append((100 * correct / len(train_dataset)))
   
    #Testing
    loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    iterations = 0

    model.eval()                    # Put the network into evaluation mode
    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(test_load):
        
        # Convert torch tensor to Variable
        inputs = Variable(inputs)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        
        CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
        if CUDA:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
        
        outputs = model(inputs)     
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels) # Calculate the loss
        loss += loss.data[0]
        # Record the correct predictions for training data
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
        
        iterations += 1

    # Record the Testing loss
    test_loss.append(loss/iterations)
    # Record the Testing accuracy
    test_accuracy.append((100 * correct / len(test_dataset)))
    stop = time.time()
    
    print ('Epoch {}/{}, Training Loss: {:.3f}, Training Accuracy: {:.3f}, Testing Loss: {:.3f}, Testing Acc: {:.3f}, Time: {}s'
           .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, train_loss[-1], train_accuracy[-1], test_loss[-1], test_accuracy[-1], stop-start))
    

# Loss
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(train_loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(test_loss, label='Testing Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Accuracy
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='Testing Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Run this if you want to save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'Cats-Dogs.pth')

#Run this if you want to load the model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Cats-Dogs.pth'))

def predict(img_name,model):
    image = cv2.imread(img_name)   #Read the image
    img = Image.fromarray(image)      #Convert the image to an array
    img = transforms_photo(img)     #Apply the transformations 
    img = img.view(1,3,64,64)       #Add batch size 
    img = Variable(img)      
    #Wrap the tensor to a variable
    
    model.eval()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()
        img = img.cuda()

    output = model(img)
    print(output)
    print(output.data)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output,1)
    if predicted.item()==0:
        p = 'Cat'
    else:
        p = 'Dog'
    cv2.imshow('Original',image)
    return  p
    

pred = predict('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', model)
print("The Predicted Label is {}".format(pred))

#Load the DenseNet
model_conv = torchvision.models.densenet201(pretrained=True)

#Freeze all layers in the network  
for param in model_conv.parameters():  
    param.requires_grad = False
    
#Get the number of inputs of the last layer (or number of neurons in the layer preceeding the last layer)
num_ftrs = model_conv.classifier.in_features

#Reconstruct the last layer (output layer) to have only two classes 
model_conv.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

#Initiate the model on GPU
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model_conv = model_conv.cuda()

#Loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model_conv.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9) #Try Adam optimizer for better accuracy: optim.Adam(model_conv.parameters(), lr=0.001)

#Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

#Training
import time
num_epochs = 20
for epoch in range (num_epochs):
    start = time.time()
    exp_lr_scheduler.step()
    #Reset the correct to 0 after passing through all the dataset
    correct = 0
    for images,labels in dataloaders['training_set']:
        images = Variable(images)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model_conv(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()  
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1) 
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
        
    train_acc = 100 * correct / dataset_sizes['training_set'] 
    stop = time.time()
    print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Train Accuracy: {}%, Time: {:.2f}s'
            .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item(), train_acc, stop-start))
            
    
   #Testing
   model_conv.eval()  
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    start = time.time()
    for (images, labels) in dataloaders['test_set']:
        
        images = Variable(images)
        labels = Variable(labels)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = images.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()

        outputs = model_conv(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    stop = time.time()

    print('Test Accuracy: {:.3f} %, Time: {:.2f}s'.format(100 * correct / total,stop-start))

#Import your trial images and check against the model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#Predict your own image
def predict(img_name,model):
    image = cv2.imread(img_name)   #Read the image
    #ret, thresholded = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   #Threshold the image
    img = Image.fromarray(image)      #Convert the image to an array
    img = transforms_photo(img)     #Apply the transformations 
    img = img.view(1,3,224,224)       #Add batch size 
    img = Variable(img)      
   #Wrap the tensor to a variable
    
    model.eval()

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()
        img = img.cuda()

    output = model(img)
    print(output)
    print(output.data)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output,1)
    if predicted.item()==0:
        p = 'Cat'
    else:
        p = 'Dog'
    cv2.imshow('Original',image)
    return  p
```

and i got this :

I test some part of my code but it seems everything is ok aanybody can help?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2262                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2263     if dim == 2:
-> 2264         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2265     elif dim == 4:
   2266         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

IndexError: Target 3 is out of bounds.
```

i found nothing in searching the web.and also i found nothing in stack,i read its doc and i found nothing

Comment: Could you reduce your code sample with the relevant part(s), add the *full* error stack trace, and give us the input & target shapes of your tensors when calling the loss function?

Answer (score 0):

You are using classification loss (cross entropy). However, while your model predicts only one of two possible classes (the output dimension of `fc5` is 2), it appears as if your data has more classes.
Make sure the output dimension of your network matches the number of classes in your data.

BTW, [your `forward` method is not indented properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242545/1714410).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wasn't 0-indexing my classes. So it was 1,2,3 rather than 0,1,2.