# object of type 'ESC50Data' has no len() in my audio classification script

Tags: python, audio, pytorch

so I'm running into the error that my class ESC50Data does not have any length.

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
```

```
class ESC50Data(Dataset):
      def __init__(self, base, df, in_col, out_col):
        self.df = df
        self.data = []
        self.labels = []
        self.c2i={}
        self.i2c={}
        self.categories = sorted(df[out_col].unique())
        for i, category in enumerate(self.categories):
            self.c2i[category]=i
            self.i2c[i]=category
        for ind in tqdm(range(len(df))):
            row = df.iloc[ind]
            file_path = os.path.join(base,row[in_col])
            self.data.append(spec_to_image(get_melspectrogram(file_path))[np.newaxis,...])
            self.labels.append(self.c2i[row['category']])
            def __len__(self):
                                    return len(self.data)
            def __getitem__(self, idx):
                                                return self.data[idx], self.labels[idx]
```

```
train_data = ESC50Data('audio', train, 'filename', 'category')
valid_data = ESC50Data('audio', valid, 'filename', 'category')
```

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
```

This is the point at which I get my error. Using Jypter Notebooks as a sidenote.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [47], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
      2 valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:353, in DataLoader.__init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn, multiprocessing_context, generator, prefetch_factor, persistent_workers, pin_memory_device)
    351 else:  # map-style
    352     if shuffle:
--> 353         sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    354     else:
    355         sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py:106, in RandomSampler.__init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples, generator)
    102 if not isinstance(self.replacement, bool):
    103     raise TypeError("replacement should be a boolean value, but got "
    104                     "replacement={}".format(self.replacement))
--> 106 if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
    107     raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
    108                      "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py:114, in RandomSampler.num_samples(self)
    110 @property
    111 def num_samples(self) -> int:
    112     # dataset size might change at runtime
    113     if self._num_samples is None:
--> 114         return len(self.data_source)
    115     return self._num_samples

TypeError: object of type 'ESC50Data' has no len()
```

Any ideas as to what could be happening? I created the class ESC50Data and then I gave it the child class called Dataset that will inherent the properties of ESC50Data. I also loaded the data into pytorch with train and valid data.

Comment: What is `self.data_source`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it seems to be from the pytorch import, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/sampler.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indentation of `__len__(self)` and `__getitem__(self, idx)` methods in your `class ESC50Data` code. Right now, it seems like these methods are defined *inside* the `__init__` method, and not under the class itself.

See, e.g.,  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242545/1714410).